# Open Mail Client through Web (Java - Spring)

Tags: java, jsp, email, client

I have a webpage running Java with Java Server Pages. I let the user determine, which other users he want to send an email to, and then go into my method, to check for their mail-addresses. After that, I would want the clients mail program to open up with the pre-filled tags (To, CC, BCC).

At the moment I use `Desktop.getDesktop().mail()`. It works perfectly well on my testserver on my pc, but not on our webserver. It produces a "Null Pointer Exception" (I guess no Mail-Client can be found on the server).

If I just send the mailto as return address of the function: `return mailto:jack-normal@abc.de?cc=abc@de.fe`, the mail client gets opened, but the user gets a blank page in the webbrowser as well! Not quiet what I want.

I found no solution searching stackoverflow for opening a web client, from the web...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with some JavaScript:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" id="mailLink">Mail</a>
<script>
document.getElementById("mailLink").onclick = function() {
    window.location = "mailto:jack-normal@abc.de?cc=abc@de.fe";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If the address is not known at this stage, you could either reload the same page and use some jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.location = "mailto:jack-normal@abc.de?cc=abc@de.fe";
});
```

Or just load the email address with an AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "mail.data",
  cache: false
}).done(function( data ) {
  window.location = data;
});
```

Comment: Yes, but the mails are not known in this step. They will be extracted in the servlet, not the jsp.